# Merge [timeline] and [facebook-timeline]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

Today I was asking a Facebook related question and I realized that there are two tags about Facebook's timeline: [facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline) and [timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/timeline). These tags have 8 and 17 posts, respectively.

Since both tags mean the same thing, I demand merging of these tags into one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The merge is done. [facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline) is now the master tag.